# bootstrap-table (wenzhixin) --> Data by Ajax

Tags: json, ajax, bootstrap-table

i want to use the bootstrap-table library from wenzhixin (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) but my skills seem not be as good enough that i can get the script running.

I want the table to be supplied with data via ajax.

Here's the code which works (example from the source page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>SL Time</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap Table -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Table -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-table-de-DE.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table id="table"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-height="460"
           data-search="true"
           data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
           data-side-pagination="server"
           data-pagination="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="nummer">Nummer</th>
            <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
// your custom ajax request here
function ajaxRequest(params) {
    // data you need
    console.log(params.data);
    // just use setTimeout
    setTimeout(function () {
        params.success({
            total: 100,
            rows: [{
                "nummer": 0,
                "name": "Item 0",
            }]
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

But i want the data coming from my page "ajax_loader.php" which looks like this:

```
<?php
$data=array();
array_push($data, array('nummer' => '1', 'name' => 'daniel'));
array_push($data, array('nummer' => '2', 'name' => 'thomas'));
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

But how do i get the following piece of code get to fill the table (as the sample function does):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_loader.php",
        data: "user-id=1",
        success: function(data) {
            // At this position my knowledge ends ;-(
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me, get the thing working?

Best regards

Daniel

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is your friend ^^ (moreover with an example : http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html#options/custom-ajax.html).
Seriously, here is the solution :

The HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <table id="table"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-height="460"
           data-search="true"
           data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
           data-side-pagination="server"
           data-pagination="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="nummer">Nummer</th>
            <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

The script :

```
// your custom ajax request here
function ajaxRequest(params) {

    // data you may need
    console.log(params.data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_loader.php",
        data: "user-id=1",
// You are expected to receive the generated JSON (json_encode($data))
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            params.success({
// By default, Bootstrap table wants a "rows" property with the data
                "rows": data,
// You must provide the total item ; here let's say it is for array length
                "total": data.length
            })
        },
        error: function (er) {
            params.error(er);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

params.success is function! You need more params, like this

```
function ajaxRequest(params) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/gruzin/getdb",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            params.success({
                "rows": data,
                "total": data.length
            },null,{});
        },
        error: function (er) {
            params.error(er);
        }
    });
}
```